# Activity to activity that holds fragments for bottom nav bar never get to fragment but to the activity that hold them by the FrameLayout

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, bottomnavigationview

I have a **SplashScreen** *Activity* that launches after checking if the user is loged in, like this :

```
 /* New Handler to start the Home-Activity
     * and close this Splash-Screen after some seconds.*/
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            /* Create an Intent that will start the Menu-Activity. */
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, HomeActivity.class);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            startActivity(intent);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);
```

- Whenever the splash screen ends, it launches to the **MainScreen** *Activity* that holds the FramLayout for the fragments and the bottom navigation bar.
- But when it launches, instead to start on the HomeFragment in bottom nav bar, it shows the **HomeScreen** *Activity* Layout.
- What i want is when the **SplashScreen** *Activity* ends it goes directly to the ***HomeFragment***.
- Here the code for the **HomeScreen Activity**:

  ```
       bottomBarLayout.addTab(tab_home).addTab(tab_wish)
          .addTab(tab_notifications)
              .addTab(tab_profile)
                  .create(new BottomBarLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
              @Override
              public void onTabSelected(BottomTabView tab) {     


                  //Log.e(TAG, "onTabSelected: =="+tab.getTabPosition() );

                  Fragment selectedFragment = null;

                  switch (tab.getTabPosition()){
                      case 0:
                          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Acceuil", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                          selectedFragment = new HomeFragment();
                          break;
                      case 1:
                          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Voeux", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                          selectedFragment = new WishListFragment();
                          break;
                      case 2:
                          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Notifications", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                          selectedFragment = new NotificationsFragment();
                          break;
                      case 3:
                          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Profile", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                          selectedFragment = new ProfileFragment();
                          break;

                  }
                  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_layout,
                          selectedFragment).commit();

              }

              @Override
              public void onTabUnselected(BottomTabView tab) {

              }

              @Override
              public void onTabReselected(BottomTabView tab) {

              }
          });
  }
  ```

  - And the the FragmenHome :

    ```
    public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    public HomeFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    }
    }
    ```

Comment: Can you post the home activity xml file? If the following portion **R.id.frame_layout** in home activity it will replace with home fragment UI.

Comment: it's below, i couldn't add it to the main question.

Comment: it's fixed freind.

Answer (score 0):

So I fixed the problem that i had with this simple method in my MainsScreen activity :

```
private void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment){
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, fragment);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

and called it in the onCreate like this :

```
replaceFragment(new HomeFragment());
```

HomeFragment is the fragment that i want to go when the splash screnends, and now when it ends, it goes directly to the firs tab on the bottom navigation bar.